# ASP.NET MVC async chaining causing 100% cpu utilization

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I am developing ASP.NET MVC application and using `await`/`async`. I have folowing method in my controller:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> PrintCachePartial()
{
    var cacheItems = await cacheProvider.GetPrintCacheItems();
    return View(cacheItems);
}
```

Then it calls `cacheProvider.GetPrintCacheItems()`:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<PrintCacheItem>> GetPrintCacheItems()
{
    var res = await atrServiceFacade.GetCacheList(CacheType.PrintCache);
    var entities = DataSetToCacheItemEntities(res.dataSet).ToArray();
    return entities;
}
```

This calls `atrServiceFacade.GetCacheList()`:

```cs
public Task<AtrDataSetResult> GetCacheList(CacheType cacheType)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<AtrDataSetResult>();
    var client = serviceFactory.GetATRServiceClient();
    client.CacheListCompleted += (sender, args) => AsyncHelper.AsyncCompleted(sender, args, tcs);
    client.CacheListAsync(cacheType);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

This is just a task wrapper for SOAP service.

It looks it work ok but the problem is that everytime the page is refreshed (controller method called), CPU utilization of IIS proces raises about 30%. So it quickly get to 100%.

I assume is is because of `await`/`async` but I am not sure.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4, targeting .NET 4. For `await`/`async` compatibility I am using  `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` library.

Comment: Why do you assume that? Have you checked without it using synchronous calls?

Comment: You are actually right, when I call it synchronously it's the same.

Comment: My first guess would be `DataSetToCacheItemEntities` but you need real profiling.

Comment: [`async`/`await` is undefined on ASP.NET if you use the Microsoft.Bcl.Async library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx). This is an unsupported scenario; you should update to 4.5.

Comment: The problem occurs only whe Visual Studio (2013) is running. When solution is not opened in VS it runs fine. When I open the solution in VS and not even run the debugger the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like i Mentioned in the comment above. I didn't have anything to do with `await`/`async`.

The high CPU showed only when Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 was running and the solution opened.  When I closed VS everything was OK.

After installing VS Update 3 RC is everything OK so it was just a bug of VS.

[source](http://forums.asp.net/t/1992990.aspx?IIS%20Express%20high%20CPU%20usage%20VS2013)